# Page can have only Window or Frame as parent

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I just want to switch between WPF pages, but getting above mentioned error:Page can have only Window or Frame as parent.
here is my code

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Public Class Page1

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Try

        Dim dd As New Page2


        Me.Content = dd
        Me.txt1.Text = (dd.txt10.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception

        txt1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
```

xaml file code

```
<Page x:Class="Page2"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Page2">
<Grid>

    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="163,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Height="55"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="38,81,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

please guide me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: no i did not remove it my error changed but still problem not solved so that i posted it with new error message . first error was about to "show.me" second one above here described ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the name Page1 I assume it is a Page.  Put a Frame in Page1 and load Page2 into the Frame.

Comment: who to do it please explain with code example please ?

Comment: i try this  Dim dd As New Page2

me.show=dd
        Me.Content = dd
both not working i want to open new windoe